# Getting the alphabet of a language from the Locale in Java

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, alphabet

I am making an internationalized app in Java. I need a list of all the letters in a language, starting from the Locale. There are some questions like [Alphabet constant in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205771/alphabet-constant-in-java) or [Create Alphabet List from list : Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098295/create-alphabet-list-from-list-java) which touch on the issue, but I'm wondering is there a Utils class or something where it's already defined and where I can get a list of chars or a String containing all the letters in the alphabet of a language by it's Locale.

Comment: See [How can I determine what the alphabet for a locale is in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417377/how-can-i-determine-what-the-alphabet-for-a-locale-is-in-java).

Answer (score 5):

You can refer this library and methods in detail, [com.ibm.icu.util.LocaleData](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html#getExemplarSet(com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale,%20int,%20int)). Pass argument as `Locale.ENGLISH` to get alphabets of English.

Comment: Here's the spoiler:  
`com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale ulocale = new com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale(java.util.Locale.forLanguageTag("pl"));  
com.ibm.icu.util.LocaleData.getExemplarSet(ulocale,com.ibm.icu.util.LocaleData.ES_STANDARD);`
this returns:  
`[a-pr-uwyzóąćęłńśźż]`

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here.

First, I have to point out that there are many languages that [aren't alphabetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems). Obviously, Chinese, or Japanese are examples of ideographic languages. Unfortunately, it will be very hard, next to impossible to create a list of all the characters in these languages.

Second, although [Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) and as a consequence [ICU](http://icu-project.org/) have predefined sets of [index exemplars](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/27/by_type/core_data.alphabetic_information.index.html) and [example characters](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/27/by_type/core_data.alphabetic_information.main.html) this information is far from being complete.

Third, there are languages that use more than one [script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_system) (aka writing system). Depending on the source of your locale you may or may not know which characters needs to be displayed.

Finally, it is hard to give you right answer when you haven't provided your use case. The design of your application may impose serious limitations on usability or localizability...

Comment: Thank you, but it's actually very easy to give me the right answer since I was just wondering if someone can point me to something I described, not solve all my problems.